# Well vs good........proper vs conversational

Tags: word-choice

Proper answer friendly greeting, "How are you?" I am "well" or I am "good"

"I am well" sounds like I'm saying I'm not sick. "I'm good," or "good" accompanied by a friendly nod sounds much better.

Answer (score 1):

In the immortal words of Tracy Jordan ["Superman does good, you're doing well"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFBYz.jpg)

More seriously, [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/good-versus-well?page=1) says either is okay, and "I'm good" is much more common in casual conversation.

Personally, I had enough teachers in my schooling tell me not to say "I'm good" that I usually respond "I'm fine", "can't complain", "not bad", "great!", or something of that nature, since "I'm well" does sound awkward.